# How to train a neural network with a single digit output?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

my goal is to build a neural network with Tensorflow that receives a 128-dim vector as input and assigns a rating (0.0-5.0).

**The problem**: Accuracy remains at 0.0 regardless of how many epochs I'm using

This is what I got so far

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle


#Load data frame containing training data
with open("label_train_vector.txt", "rb") as f: 
   df_train = pickle.load(f)


#Transform training data to correct format
feature_train_list = df_train['feature_vector'].to_list()
train_input = np.array(feature_train_list)
train_label_rating = df_train['rating'].to_numpy()/5


rating_model = keras.Sequential([
    
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="sigmoid", input_shape=(128,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
])

rating_model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss="mse", metrics=["accuracy"])
rating_model.fit(train_input, train_label_rating, epochs=10)
```

The output of this code is

```
Epoch 1/10
104/104 [==============================] - 1s 992us/step - loss: 0.0280 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/10
104/104 [==============================] - 0s 979us/step - loss: 0.0140 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/10
104/104 [==============================] - 0s 994us/step - loss: 0.0111 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/10
104/104 [==============================] - 0s 929us/step - loss: 0.0093 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/10
104/104 [==============================] - 0s 934us/step - loss: 0.0082 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/10
104/104 [==============================] - 0s 938us/step - loss: 0.0080 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/10
104/104 [==============================] - 0s 929us/step - loss: 0.0079 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/10
104/104 [==============================] - 0s 936us/step - loss: 0.0074 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/10
104/104 [==============================] - 0s 930us/step - loss: 0.0074 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 10/10
104/104 [==============================] - 0s 923us/step - loss: 0.0073 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

The accuracy does not change during the training process, but I can't figure out where things go wrong.

Comment: This is not a correct setup. Despite of all `sigmoid` gives output between 0 and 1. How will you predict anything greater than 1?

Comment: I adjusted your point by normalizing the rating to [0,1] but the same problem remains.

Comment: If this is a regression problem (as implied by using `loss="mse"`), accuracy is meaningless, and `activation="sigmoid"` is wrong. Additionally, we don't use `sigmoid` activation for intermediate layers - http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 0):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle


#Load data frame containing training data
with open("label_train_vector.txt", "rb") as f: 
   df_train = pickle.load(f)


#Transform training data to correct format
feature_train_list = df_train['feature_vector'].to_list()
train_input = np.array(feature_train_list)
train_label_rating = df_train['rating'].to_numpy()/5


rating_model = keras.Sequential([
    
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", input_shape=(128,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
])

rating_model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss="mse", metrics=["accuracy"])
rating_model.fit(train_input, train_label_rating, epochs=10)
```

may be better